# gradle: for taskB to run after taskA whenever taskA is run

Tags: gradle

I'm having trouble figuring out how to force a task to always run after another one.  I'm aware of `dependsOn`, but `taskA.dependsOn taskB` will cause taskB to execute first.  I'm also aware of `mustRunAfter` and `shouldRunAfter`, but `taskB.mustRunAfter taskA` does not force taskB to run, it only ensures that IF both are called, taskA runs first.  IF I use both, I get a circular dependency error.

I want `gradle taskA` to cause taskA to run, then taskB to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for [finalizer tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks).  Use the method `finalizedBy()`:

```
taskA.finalizedBy taskB
```

Comment: @JaredBurrows Can't for 2 days

Comment: Ah, you just answered!